# encount DOMException when remove node

Tags: java, android

i encount DOMException.HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR when navigate the Document object to remove a pecific node, and after google this error code, It says:

"HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: Raised if this node is of a type that does not allow children of the type of the newChild node, or if the node to insert is one of this node's ancestors or this node itself, or if this node is of type Document and the DOM application attempts to insert a second DocumentType or Element node"

I have check the node type which i want to remove, both Element and Text type will cause the exception

here is my code

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(smil.getBytes()));

        Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();

        Node node = root.getFirstChild();
        dom.removeChild(node);
```

it goes

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException

at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.InnerNodeImpl.removeChild(InnerNodeImpl.java:180)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one method can solve this situation

change

```
    dom.removeChild(node);
```

to

```
    node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
```

it seems works for me :-)